# py -m baselines.run yields "No module named baselines.run"

Tags: python, openai-gym

Most examples on the [openai/baselines page](https://github.com/openai/baselines) go about the command `python -m baselines.run ...`. I can't seem to get my installation to work.

Creating a venv and then running the command:

```bash
py -3.9 -m venv venv
venv\scripts\activate
(venv) pip install baselines
# Collecting baselines
# ... (successfully installs packages)
py -m baselines.run
# .\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named baselines.run
```

Info about the venv:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.9.13
- pip 22.0.4

(I used python 3.9 rather than 3.11 because the latest version seems to have issues with installing pygame)

I can't find anything referring to this to this error, so surely I must be doing something wrong? Am I supposed to install something else? Do I have to run this in WSL?